# Create Georeferenced Map in R?

Tags: raster, r, pdf, avenza

Looking to make geo-reference pdfs (or tiff) of the sort that can be used by the Avenza application in R. Can anyone provide some advice on tools that may be able to convert an R plot into a georeferenced pdf or tiff?.

I have made a stab at my own function to do this (tiff), but while the resulting map is roughly in the right place, it is scaled slightly incorrectly.

```
map2tiff=function(tiff_out
                 ,dir_temp="c:\\temp"
                 ,ext #required, extent of first object plotted
                 #,crs=NA
                 ,res=300
                 ,xy_inches=6
){

  require("raster")

  #query graphics
  graph_in=recordPlot()
  par_in=par()
  dims_in=dev.size(units = c("in", "cm", "px"))
  mai_in=par_in$mai
  pin_in=par_in$pin
  plt_in=par_in$plt
  usr_in = par_in$usr
  din_in = par_in$din
  fin_in = par_in$fin

  #manually calculate mai - default mai does not account for legend when plotting a raster imager
  mai_in = c(plt_in[3] * fin_in[2],plt_in[1] * fin_in[1],fin_in[2] - plt_in[4] * fin_in[2],fin_in[1] - plt_in[2] * fin_in[1])*1.5

  #compute new graph dimensions etc.
  dx=xmax(ext) - xmin(ext)
  dy=ymax(ext) - ymin(ext)
  x_rat=min(1,dx/dy)
  y_rat=min(1,dy/dx)
  x_in = xy_inches[1]*x_rat + sum(mai_in[c(2,4)])
  y_in = xy_inches[1]*y_rat + sum(mai_in[c(1,3)])
  xrat= dx / x_in
  yrat= dy / y_in
  xyrat = min(xrat,yrat)

  #create new extent to include margins
  lx=xmin(ext) - mai_in[2] * xrat
  ly=ymin(ext) - mai_in[1] * yrat
  ux=xmax(ext) + mai_in[4] * xrat
  uy=ymax(ext) + mai_in[3] * yrat

  #export plot to a file
  tif_temp=file.path(dir_temp,gsub("[.]tif","_temp.tif",basename(tiff_out)))
  tiff(tif_temp,height=y_in,width=x_in,units="in",res=res)
  replayPlot(graph_in)
  dev.off()

  #load and georeference map
  r_map = brick(tif_temp)
  extent(r_map) = c(lx,ux,ly,uy)

  #write final geo-referenced raster
  writeRaster(r_map,filename=tiff_out,overwrite=T)
  unlink(tif_temp)

}

library(raster)

set.seed(55)

xy=data.frame(x=rnorm(50)*5000+200,y=rnorm(50)*15000+200)
coordinates(xy)=~x+y
rtest=raster(ext=extent(xy),res=50)
rtest[] = rnorm(length(rtest))
writeRaster(rtest,"c:\\temp\\tiff001.tif",overwrite=T)

plot(rtest)
plot(xy,add=T,pch=16)

map2tiff(tiff_out="c:\\temp\\maptiff001.tif",ext=extent(rtest))

rdat=raster("c:\\temp\\tiff001.tif")
rmap=raster("c:\\temp\\maptiff001.tif")
```

## the rasters in the two plots should exactly overlap, but don't:

```
plotRGB(rmap)
plot(rdat,add=T,alpha=.5)
```